# Convert a series of character of different single quotes to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, devexpress, nvarchar, single-quotes

I am working on an SQL query which uses multiple queries which use temp tables to prepare required data to the final report query. An application which uses DevExpress reporting engine, generates a "where" clause automatically according to some pre-settings. The result of the desired filter is something like this:

```
-- the part "where 1=1" is not generated. it is added for the purpose of visualizing and demonstrating
where 1=1  AND (@inv IN(4)) AND (@date = convert(datetime, '2021-02-21 23:59:59:000', 121) )
```

I would like to convert the generated filter into a nvarchar for farther string process, but the single quote in the convert function for the date will always ruin any trial of surrounding the statements with single quote(s) for escaping.

so my question is, considering that I have a statement like:

```
AND (@para1 IN(4)) AND (@date = convert(datetime, '2021-02-21 23:59:59:000', 121) )
```

how could I deal with it as string of type nvarchar using SQL Server for farther parsing?
knowing that I have no control over the code of the application which generates the filter string

Edit2:

Additionally knowing that adding quotes is only allowed at the beginning and end only,
and the Application which generates the filters is a compiled app. The app takes the original SQL query with a placeholder {0} to fill up the generated filters. Unfortunately, the app does not allow using next placeholder which should be {1}, so I am stuck to use the whole filter string using placeholder {0} only. So, If there is something in SQL or idea that could convert the generated filter string mentioned above to an nvarchar, so that I could write a function to take the values of each filter and reuse them into my SQL query

Comment: So are you saying you want to use dynamic SQL? If so you escape single quotes by doubling them.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case here, I can only place single quotes at the being and end only.

Comment: Its not clear how you would use your string once you make it? But no environment I know of prevents you from escaping characters... its necessary for all string handling.

Comment: The Application which generates the filters is a compiled app. The app takes the original SQL query with a placeholder {0} to fill up the generated filters. Unfortunately, the app does not allow using next placeholder which should be {1}, so I am stuck to use the whole filter string using placeholder {0} only. So, If there is something in SQL or idea that could convert the generated filter string mentioned above to an nvarchar, so that I could write a function to take the values of each filter and reuse them into my SQL query.